# React state disappears when I refresh the page

Tags: reactjs

If i reload the page my user data is lost from state, how can i handle this

before reload

[image]

after reload

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you refresh the page, browser loads your app from again. So it renders and mounts your components for the first time. So your state will be lost. You want to persist your state? Or Are are facing issues during development when you update your code and you want to see the change you made?

Comment: I want to keep my status yeah @c0m1t

Comment: State will be lost on refresh, if you want to persist state, use localstorage or a db

Comment: I'm using a db. I keep the state while redirecting from the login page to the /home router, but it goes away when I refresh.

Comment: Please provide a least reproducible code instead of provide images of your code